# Почему gulp не видит вновь созданную папку?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Я использую Gulp 4 и у меня есть таск, который локально деплоит код:

```
gulp.task('deploy', gulp.series('clean', 'handlers:all', 'deployment'));
```

Задача состоит из трех подзадач:

1. Таск `clean`: удаляет папку build.
2. Таск `handlers:all`: вновь создает эту папку и выплевывает туда файлы (html, css, js, ...)
3. Таск `deployment`: берет содержимое папки build и переносит туда, куда я прошу это сделать.

Проблема в deployment. Он выглядит примерно вот так:

```
gulp.task('deployment', done => {
    gulp.src('./build/')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../other-project/'));
});
```

У меня в проекте все несколько сложнее, но суть такая же. Дело в том, что gulp.src просто не находит папку build потому что ее удалил таск `clean`. Если поставить небольшой таймаут, то файлы считаются:

```
gulp.task('deployment', done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        gulp.src('./build/')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('../other-project/'));
    }, 2000);
});
```

Но проблема в том, что это не очень надежно потому что со временем таймаута не угадаешь.

Как правильно отлавливать такое?

Answer (score 0):

В моем коде были проблемы.

Во-первых, я неправильно завершал задачу `clean`. Было:

```
gulp.task('clean', done => {
    del('./build/');
    done();
});
```

Стало:

```
gulp.task('clean', done => {
    del('./build/').then(() => {
        done()
    });
});
```

То есть задача завершается только после того, как полностью отработает.

Во-вторых, подобная проблема была с остальными задачами. Я вызвал done() просто в конце задачи:

```
gulp.task('styles', done => {
    gulp.src(...)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(...))

    done();
});
```

А нужно было сделать вот так:

```
gulp.task('styles', done => {
    gulp.src(...)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(...))
        .on('end', done);
});
```